Passing env variable inputs to a reusable workflow after copying files
I am trying to use this github actions pipeline. I am trying to reference the environment I stored in GITHUB_ENV and access it in the reusable workflow.
I need access to the file so I can somehow reference that in my terraform workflow. But once I copy it over, I cannot reference the said file in my terraform.
name: Main Workflow

jobs:
  job1:
    name: copy file from one folder to another
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Copy file and Store in Github ENV
        run: |
          mkdir -p temp
          cp path1/path2/api_gw.yaml temp/api_gw.yaml
          echo "FILE_PATH=temp/copied_file.txt" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  

  terraform-plan:
    needs: [job1]
    uses: repo/workflows/.github/reusable-workflow.yaml
    # This action runs checkout and extracts everything in the TF folder so it runs tf plan, this workflow is not something we can modify
    with:
      metadata: ${{ needs.metadata.outputs.metadata }}
      token:    ${{ input.token }}
      env:      dev 

TF Code:
module "apigw" {

 source = 'some/path'
 name = 'random_apigw'
 body = templateFile(var.FILE_PATH, { other vars })

}


In my vars.tf file I defined the FILE_PATH variable as such:
variable FILE_PATH" { 
description = 'file path'
type = string
}


In my .tfvars file, I defined the path as:
FILE_PATH = "temp/api_gw.yaml"

Reusable workflow on-params:
on: 
 workflow-dispatch:
  inputs:
   metadata:
    required:true
    desc: something
   token:
    required:true
    desc: something
   path:
    required:false
    desc: something
   env:
    required:true
    desc: something

EDIT: Added reusable params, these are all currently being used in the workflow
Obviously this approach is not working, and I am unsure why its not. Am I referencing the global items incorrectly or is it because its being overriden?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Please show us repo/workflows/.github/reusable-workflow.yaml.

@Schwern We cannot edit that file so we cannot add or delete anything there, so unfortunately posting it here wouldnt help.

You don't have to edit the reusable workflow. What we need to see is its on.workflow_call definition.

@Schwern Added them


Did you paste them correctly? It looks like path and env are incorrectly indented, and that changes the meaning of the YAML. 2) Those inputs are all required, yet you're not passing any inputs to the reusable workflow in your Main Workflow.


So path and env are in the same indent as metadata and token. I just fixed it, thank you for pointing that out. I am passing all of these but they are being used in the other jobs in yaml file. I didnt write all that out, because the file is 500 or so lines long.

If it's public, can you provide a link to the reusable workflow?

Its not public, I added the inputs I pass into the reusable workflow in the question. Hope that helps.

metadata should be metadata_json. and you're missing path. Sorry, I don't believe this question can be answered without seeing the reusable workflow, or at least an error message.

I fixed the metadata, and path is not required. I copied it wrong while pasting here. There is no error per se at this step. It fails when I try to read the file from the temp path from terraform. Thats when terraform says "file not found in this path". I am just not sure the path (or the file) exists by the time we get to the reusable workflow even thought I storing it to GITHUB_ENV

Reusable workflows do not have access to the caller's environment variables. From Reusing Workflows: Limitations...

Any environment variables set in an env context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow are not propagated to the called workflow. For more information, see "Store information in variables" and "Accessing contextual information about workflow runs."
Similarly, environment variables set in the env context, defined in the called workflow, are not accessible in the env context of the caller workflow. Instead, you must use outputs of the reusable workflow. For more information, see "Using outputs from a reusable workflow."

Instead, you have to pass inputs to the resuable workflow using with and secrets with secrets.
  terraform-plan:
    needs: [job1]
    uses: repo/workflows/.github/reusable-workflow.yaml
    with:
      this: that
    secrets:
      key: value

See Passing inputs and secrets to a reusable workflow.
Exactly how you do this will be defined in the reusable workflow. Something like this.
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      this:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      key:
        required: true

See Using inputs and secrets in a reusable workflow and on.workflow_call.

Hi, thanks for answering! Unfortunately I do not have access to the reusable workflow and will not be able to edit any variables there. Is there any way I could do it without editing the reusable workflow?

@vampyfreak You don't have to edit the reusable workflow. You have to change how you're calling it. The information about how to pass variables and secrets to the reusable workflow will be inside the reusable workflow in on.workflow_call. I've updated the answer to show what you're looking for.

I added them but I cannot edit anything on the reusable workflow, as it is protected by our org and would take a long time to get those changes propagated.

@vampyfreak Again, you don't have to edit the reusable workflow. You have to edit your own workflow to pass in the inputs required by the reusable workflow using with.

I get what you are saying, I am just trying to figure out how I can pass what I want in those variables, thats all.

@vampyfreak That is specific to the reusable workflow. Either it's documented in the reusable workflow, or you can figure it out by reading the reusable workflow.

I added the inputs that i pass into the reusable action. I hope that helps. Sorry I didnt realize thats what you were asking for. Brain fart. Have been looking at this all day.
